# define structure with bit fields and unions

Tags: c++

The environment is a 32bit ESP32 using Arduino IDE

This structure GlobalAspects sizeof = 4 which is expected.

```
struct GlobalAspects
{
    uint8_t Gasp;
    uint8_t MastType;
    unsigned Flags:4;
    unsigned slTOP:4;
    unsigned slMID:4;
    unsigned slBOT:4;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Works with this data ( the complete table has 37 rows ).

```
GlobalAspects AspectTest[ 5 ] = 
//     -------------------
{
 {asp292,  M3m,  0b0111, 0b0100, 0b0100, 0b0100}, // R  R  R
 {asp292,  M2m,  0b0110, 0b0100, 0b0100, 0b0000}, // R  R  _
 {asp292,  M2d,  0b0110, 0b0100, 0b0100, 0b0000}, // R  R  _
 {asp292,  M1m,  0b0100, 0b0100, 0b0000, 0b0000}, // R  _  _
 {asp292,  M1d,  0b0100, 0b0100, 0b0000, 0b0000}  // R  _  _
};
```

'*******************************

The problem:

This struct GlobalAspectsX below sizeof = 2 ???? expected = 4

The intent is to be able to transfer the four bit fields as a single uint16_t variable.

```
struct GlobalAspectsX
{
    uint8_t Gasp;
    uint8_t MastType;
    union bits4
    {
        uint16_t asp16;
        struct bit4Asp
        {
            unsigned Flags:4;
            unsigned slTOP:4;
            unsigned slMID:4;
            unsigned slBOT:4;
        };
    };
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Does not work with the data above "Too many initializers"

Stumped! How do I fix the GlobalAspectsX size and too many initializers???

Please advise

-George

Comment: It's declaring a nested type, not a field!

Comment: It appears the intent it to use the `union` for type punning.  That's not supported in C++.  You can only read from the field which was written to, not write to one field and read from another field.  In C++, instead use `std::memcpy` to do type punning.

Comment: By the way: `unsigned Flags:4;` means `unsigned int` is used as storage and that's likely 4 bytes on a 32bit ESP32. You should specify `uint16_t Flags:4;`.

Answer (score 0):

A union initializes the first member `uint16_t asp16;` and not the `struct bit4Asp`. So there should be only one value instead of the 4x 4bit. You might try changing the order in the union.

Also never use `packed`, it will generate slower code. Just assert the size to make sure no accidental padding occurs.

Comment: This array is used as a constant.  Will redefining as:

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to thank all of you who offered guidance!

What I did:

*Removed the packed attribute - struct size remained at 4 bytes.
*Tried memcpy, the Arduino IDE would not let me take the address of the Flags bit field as the source address.
*Of course, I most likely missed something... but, for now I have a solution.

I created an **attribute**((always_inline)) routine using bit shifts to assemble the desired unsigned 16 bit variable.

```
uint16_t Aspect16 ( int asp ) __attribute__((always_inline));

uint16_t Aspect16 ( int asp )
//       --------------------
{
    uint16_t Aspbits;
    
    Aspbits =  ( ASPECT[ asp ].Flags << 12 );
    Aspbits |= ( ASPECT[ asp ].slTOP << 8 );
    Aspbits |= ( ASPECT[ asp ].slMID << 4 );
    Aspbits |= ( ASPECT[ asp ].slBOT );
    
    return Aspbits;
}
```

I would welcome any corrective followup.